# BindingExpression path error in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have problem in my binding and I don't know why. I am using `Devexpress MVVM`. I have a user control which I used to populate textbox based on my `ObservableCollection` which is working well.

I have this xaml code in my user control.

```
<ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListControls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding RGN_INdex}" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding RGN}" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding InsertControlCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RGN_INdex }" />
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>
                <Label Grid.Column="2"  Content="RSN:" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding RSN}" Grid.Column="3" />
                <Label Grid.Column="4"  Content="SGN:" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding SGN}" Grid.Column="5" />
                <Label Grid.Column="6"  Content="SN:" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding SN}" Grid.Column="7" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The above code is working until I add the `InsertControlCommand` .

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
     <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding InsertControlCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RGN_INdex }" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

It gives me:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'InsertControlCommand' property not found on 'object' ''RelativesM' (HashCode=41849684)'. BindingExpression:Path=InsertControlCommand; DataItem='RelativesM' (HashCode=41849684); target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=2666760); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Why does it doesn't find the `InsertControlCommand` when that command and the `ListControls` ObservableCollection are in the same Class(ViewModel)?

This is my `ViewModelBase` where the `InsertControlCommand` and `ListControls` are located.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public DelegateCommand<object> InsertControlCommand { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model.RelativesM> ListControls { get; set; }
    public ViewModelBase() {
    InsertControlCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(InsertControlEvent);
    ListControls = new ObservableCollection<Model.RelativesM>();
    }
}
```

Then I have this MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    }
```

Then on my MainWindow.xaml I set the DataContext with this code:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Upon my understanding my code should work. Because the `ListControls` and `InsertControlCommand` use the same ViewModel, but the command doesn't. What is the reason? What did I miss?

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it doesn't find the InsertControlCommand when that command and the ListControls ObservableCollection are in the same Class(ViewModel)?

Because you have one `TextBox` per item in the `ObservableCollection<Model.RelativesM>` and the `DataContext` of each `TextBox` is the current `RelativesM` model object in the `ObservableCollection<Model.RelativesM>` and not the view model itself.

To be able to bind to a property of the view model, you could use a `{RelativeSource}` binding as suggested by @LittleBit:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RGN}" Grid.Column="1" >
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertControlCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RGN_INdex }" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I choose this answer because its a bit detailed which i understand better.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind it like this, it wont look for the InsertControlCommand in your DataContext (MainViewModel) but in your RelativesM Class. This is clearly displayed in your Error Message:

> 'InsertControlCommand' property not found on 'object' ''RelativesM'

Change your Binding of the Command to;

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertControlCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

And it should work as you expected.